# svgpanzoom - add padding on reset

Tags: svgpanzoom

Tell me please is there a way to set some padding for svg when pressing reset?

[image]

The lib scales it as close as possible to the border, I'd like to make reset works like shown on the right side of the screen.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: I just used custom controls and common zoom 0.9 both on svg init and reset click.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70510862/modify-actions-of-reset-control. Although the question is still open, I got my changed reset() to function properly by calling center() and zoom(), rather than resetPan() and resetZoom(). It's odd that the latter fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to achieve that from configs. Some possible solutions:

**Use custom controls:**

- Disable default controls
- Add your own controls ([example](http://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/demo/custom-controls.html)).
- On initialisation - store SVG pan and zoom values
- When clicking on reset button - zoom and pan with such values so that it will be padded

**Adjust the SVG:**

You can add an invisible rectangle that would be of the size of your SVG plus the padding. This way the library will think that SVG size is a bit wider, so reset will look like it has padding.

Answer (score 1):

Use `zoomBy` function of `svgpanzoom`:

```
// Zoom by 98%
panZoomTiger.zoomBy(0.98)
```