# Modify Actions of Reset Control

Tags: javascript, svgpanzoom

I wanted to execute some additional code when the panzoom 'reset' option is selected by the end-user, but there is no `setOnReset` API. I was looking for a recommended way of executing custom code in addition to the standard `resetZoom()` and `resetPan()`.

[Edited] However, I think my problem is deeper which is why I have modified the title. The additional code was to reset to a zoom level of say 0.98 (rather than 1) so that a small margin is left around the outermost shapes -- otherwise they're right up against the SVG border if `fit:true` which looks awful.

I had tried simply overriding the standard `reset()` as follows:

```
pzInst.reset = function() {
    pzInst.resetPan(); pzInst.resetZoom(); pzInst.zoomBy(0.95);
}
```

But it does not work: the SVG no longer centers, and seems to go to the top-left. I have tried 3.5.2 and 3.6.1 but the effect is the same.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to achieve what I want?